# How to use both default arguments and asterisk (*) in a function definition

Tags: python, file, logging, try-catch

I'm trying to log some `message` into a text file, and may also log an error if there was one.
I want to log to multiple files, but only print once, and using the same function.

Current Implementation:

```
def log_and_sysout(log_file, message, e=''):
    '''
    Writes logs and outputs to terminal 
    
    Params: 
        log_file:  File to log to 
        message:   -
        e:         Error, if there is one 
    '''
    sys.stdout.write(message)
    with open(log_file, "a") as f:
        f.write(message + str(e))


try: 
    # Logic

    success_message = 'Translations: Success \n'
    log_and_sysout(log_path_1, success_message)
    log_and_sysout(log_path_2, success_message)
except Exception as e: 
    fail_message = 'Translations: Fail \n'
    log_and_sysout(log_path_1, fail_message, e)
    log_and_sysout(log_path_2, fail_message, e)
```

I want something like this:

```
def log_and_sysout(*log_files, message, e=''):
    sys.stdout.write(message)
    for file in log_files:
        with open(file, "a") as f:
            f.write(message + str(e))


try: 
    # Logic

    success_message = 'Translations: Success \n'
    log_and_sysout(log_path_1, log_path_2, success_message)
except Exception as e: 
    fail_message = 'Translations: Fail \n'
    log_and_sysout(log_path_1, log_path_2, fail_message, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are almost there:

```
success_message = 'Translations: Success \n'
log_and_sysout(log_path_1, log_path_2, message=success_message)
```

However, I would suggest you to define your function like that to avoid the parameter assignment:

```
def log_and_sysout(message, e=‘’, *list_file)
```

Last but not least, you might consider the library ‘logging’ for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I made the change - I'm now getting an error that `*` is a SyntaxError from the function definition

Comment: Also, didn't know there was a "logging" function - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
It seems that the correct format is

```
def log_and_sysout(message, *log_files, e=''):
    sys.stdout.write(message)
    for file in log_files:
        with open(file, "a") as f:
            f.write(message + str(e))


log_and_sysout(message, log_path_1, log_path_2)
```